# My Spring Validation stopped working and I can't figure out why

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I was recently working with Spring Validation, I got it to work using CodeTutrs example, and then went on to other parts of my code, when I came back to it, it no longer validated user input before hitting the database. So I get Hibernate errors that say, I can't enter "null" values.

Below is the code for my JSP. I tried to revert back to my original code but it still won't validate.

```
          <form:form action="regSubmit" method="post" modelattribute="registeredUsers">
               <div style="float:left; margin-left:200px">
                <font size="5">Register</font><br><br>
                User Name: <input type="text" name="username"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="username" cssclass="error"/></font><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="password" cssclass="error"/></font><br>
                First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="first_name" cssclass="error"/></font><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="last_name" cssclass="error"/></font><br>
                Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="email" cssclass="error"/></font><br>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
               </div>
         </form:form>
```

The code for my controller is below.

```
package controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import dao.RegisteredUsers;


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/regSubmit")
    public class RegisterController
    {
        String next;
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String regUser(@Valid RegisteredUsers registeredUsers, BindingResult result,  ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Inside Register controller");

            String user = request.getParameter("username");
            String pass = request.getParameter("password");
            String fname = request.getParameter("first_name");
            String lname = request.getParameter("last_name");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            dao.RegisterUser.registerUser(user, pass, fname, lname, email);


            if (result.hasErrors())
            {
                return "RegisterLogin";
            }

            map.addAttribute("message", "Succesfully saved User "+ registeredUsers.toString());

            /*map.addAttribute("user", user);*/

            /*dao.Selector.whatToDo(user, pass, fname, lname, email);*/
            next = "RegSuccess";
            return next;
        }
    }
```

The  dao.registeredUsers, is my POJO.

The code for my POJO is below:

```
    @Component
    @Entity(name="REGISTERED_USER")
    public class RegisteredUsers 
     {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
int user_id;

@Column
    @NotEmpty
    String username;
    @NotEmpty
    String password;
    @NotEmpty
    String first_name;
    @NotEmpty
    String last_name;
    @NotEmpty @Email
    String email;

            /*getters and setters*/
```

The code for my RegisterUser is below:

```
   public class RegisterUser 
  {
public static String username;
public static String password;
public static String fname;
public static String lname;
public static String email;

public static void registerUser(String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String email)
{
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-user.xml");
    UserRoster roster= (UserRoster)ctx.getBean("user");
    RegisteredUsers u = new RegisteredUsers();

    //from register controller to set the user information 
    u.setUsername(username); 
    u.setPassword(password);
    u.setFirst_name(first_name);
    u.setLast_name(last_name);
    u.setEmail(email);

    // actually add the user to the DB
    roster.addUser(u);


}
```

I have gone over this a few times and can't figure out where my code has gone wrong.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add your RegisteredUsers class as well as the code of your static method `dao.RegisterUser.registerUser(user, pass, fname, lname, email)`? Also, why are you using plain input fields for user, password, first_name, etc. and why aren't you directly binding these to your RegisteredUsers class using `<form:input path="xxx" />` tags?

Comment: @Gummyball    I have added the code that you requested. I had tried to bind directly with using form:input, but no text fields showed up when i followed the example i followed, also when i added them, it didn't fix the issue. My initial thought was that i forgot the binding somewhere along the line, but i went over it and cant seem to see any issues. also it worked before.

Comment: you should be able to use `<form:input path="username" />` instead of `<input type="text" name="username"/>`, and it should show input text fields. That fact that you didn't get any text fields is telling. Could you maybe also add the part of the controller that sets up your JSP, the GET so to speak.
On a different note: in your RegisterUser class you're building your own Spring context every time you want to register a new user. Why not use Spring's main strength and inject your dependencies?

Comment: For Spring binding to work you'll also need to have @ModelAttribute in your Controller method like so: `public String regUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registeredUsers") RegisteredUsers registeredUsers, BindingResult result,  ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception`

Comment: Ahh, i see, ok thanks @Gummyball, i am new to Spring and Hibernate so the elegance of my code is still lacking, and i am just trying to get a hang of things. i will try what you suggest in the code!! thanks again for your help

Comment: I figured out what was wrong....it turns out i'm an idiot. Somehow, in my controller, my call to the database got placed before checking for errors, so no matter what i did, it would still send data to the database before checking for errors, and therefore cause errors. However, your help did clear up some other issues that i had, so thank you very much for your help!!! @Gummyball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your POJO class

BTW follow this link

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

this is a perfect example to follow.

1) On jsp you have not shown any error
2) You have not shown POJO, put validation on them if not done.
3) before saving result using dao check for error on high priority i.e. on start of function

Comment: i have placed the code that you requested. Thanks for the link, i will definitely take a look at it, thank you!!

Comment: In Dao on variable or Column Entry just put validations as @NotEmpty etc. It will work.

Comment: i added the Annotations like you suggested but it still won't validate before trying to send data to the database. when you say in Dao, you mean the POJO, correct? thank you for your help!!

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, my call to the database somehow got placed before checking for my errors. when i corrected this, everything works. Thank you very much for your help, your advice did help me clarify other issues and questions that i had.